# How to use $timeout in angular js with $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, resources, timeout

I was wondering how can I use $timeout in my controller to call web api server every second? following code is my controller and custom service which I have created for this section. Now I can pull out data but because of being news I want to refresh it every second.

This is my controller

```
   (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("Myapp")
        .controller("homeController", ["newsService", homeController]);

    function homeController(newsService) {
        var hc = this;
        newsService.query(function (data) {
            hc.news = data;
        })
    }
}());
```

and following code is my custom service

```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("commonServices")
        .factory("newsService", ["$resource",
                                  "appSettings",
                                   newsService])
    function newsService($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/news");
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a service in angular js called [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```
$interval(function_to_call_every_second, 1000);
```

I would say that 1 second is too small, it will overload your webservice

Comment: would you let me know how to implement it

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for you check this out


https://jsfiddle.net/vvr9qmk9/

Comment: thank you for your answer and I do appreciate your effort but what I need is how can I  use $timeout or $interval in my code?

Comment: Modify your homeController to this

function homeController(newsService, $interval) {
    var hc = this;
    $interval(getNewsQuery, 1000);
    var getNewsQuery = function() {
        newsService.query(function(data) {
            hc.news = data;
        });
    }
}

Comment: sorry but it does not work. browser debugger said  " TypeError: $interval is not a function "

Comment: Did you add $interval in your controller dependency like this  `.controller("homeController", ["newsService","$interval", homeController]);`